# Show that on $\mathbb R^2$ the vector field $y^2\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x^2\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ is not complete

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields

How to prove that on $\mathbb R^2$ the vector field  $$y^2\frac \partial{\partial x}+x^2\frac \partial{\partial y}$$ is not complete?

I tried to solve the simultaneous ODE, but I realized that it is much complicated...

Comment: If you really mean "complete" you have to explain this notion. "Closed" and "exact" vector fields are familiar.

Comment: A vector field is called complete if every one of its flow curves exist for all time.(Wilipedia)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this vector fields is tangent to the line $x=y$. This enables to compute the orbit of the point $(1,1)$.

The solution which starts at $t=0$ at the point $(1,1)$ is $x(t)={1\over 1-t}=y(t)$. It cannot be defined for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, as it goes to $\infty$ in a finite time ($t=1$).